# Unity (and its window decorator) keeps crashing, especially when using maximised windows

Tags: unity, window-manager

I'm not sure why, but Unity crashes fairly often (roughly every 15-20 minutes).

I get various bugs, for example when I try to click on the top panel, it simply becomes *transparent*. The same thing often happens with the launcher on right.

As a somewhat separate (however related) note, very often, the window decorator crashes and doesn't restart automatically.

As a workaround I have a shortcut on my desktop to `unity --replace`, although this restart doesn't often last very long. Running `unity --reset` also doesn't seem to help me much.

It gets especially unbearable (crashes far too often) when running certain heavier applications such as Google Chrome and Netbeans, full screen.

Does anyone have any suggested fixes? Or perhaps this has been discussed elsewhere, such as on Launchpad?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: @htorque I was hoping it's a bug in something I'm doing, thanks!

Comment: [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](http://launchpad.net) and as such is now closed.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your system, maybe they fixed some of the bugs. Run 'sudo apt-get update' and then 'sudo apt-get upgrade' in your terminal or use the update manager. That should include a lot of bugfixes for your system and should make unity a bit more stable. That said, Unity is still very buggy and was quite unusable to me. I would suggest switching back to the default desktop until unity is stable enough to be used 24/7. If you cannot live without the dock, try [Cairo Dock](http://glx-dock.org/). You can choose to use the 'Ubuntu Classic' desktop from the login screen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried your suggestions to no avail, so as recommended I'll be sticking to Classic. Docky was really good to me, I wish Canonical adopted that.

Comment: @Redandwhite It is nice that Ubuntu lets any users to use the user interface they want ;)