# Lot of debconf windows

Tags: software-center, xfce, debconf

When I install a program from the software manager, I have a lot of blank debconf windows opening then disappearing.

Is this normal behaviour or should I report a bug ?

Comment: [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debconf/+bug/735070) and as such is now closed.

Answer (score 0):

If these are terminal windows, you might want to reinstall `libgtk2-perl` since the gnome frontend to debconf depends on it.