# Software Center will not open

Tags: 11.10, software-center, lenses

The Software Center will not open from the launcher and I get a segmentation fault when I try to open it from the terminal.

```
2011-10-18 20:43:45,723 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.em - INFO - EM's: 17 15 21
2011-10-18 20:43:46,396 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2011-10-18 20:43:46,453 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.utils - INFO - Softwarecenter style provider for ambiance Gtk theme: /usr/share/software-center/ui/gtk3/css/softwarecenter.css
Segmentation fault
```

However it will open with the command "sudo software-center". Once it is open it runs fine, I can install new programs and everything. apt-get and synaptic also both work fine. Also, no applications show up in the application lens when I search for them.

**Edit
This is what what I get when I run software-center --debug
http://pastebin.com/FuPFPi5f

**Edit 2
Entering gdb software-center into the terminal gives me:

```
"/usr/bin/software-center": not in executable format: File format not recognized
```

and the run command will not work.

Comment: Hm. That's not awfully helpful. Could you try running `gdb software-center`, running it (`run`), then capturing a backtrace (`bt`) when it crashes?

Comment: [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/873160) and as such is now closed.

Answer (score 1):

In your home directory go to the .cache folder and there delete the "software-center" folder. This should fix the problem.