# skype screen sharing with gnome shell 3.2 problem?

Tags: gnome, skype, screen, sharing

does anyone experience this problem: when sharing full screen on skype, using gnome shell, the panel disappears, all windows disappear and the other user don't receive the screen either. sort of a freeze.
i'm on ubuntu 11.10, oneiric ocelot. gnome shell.
how can i fix the problem, and if  it's a bug. who should i report it to? gnome or skype?

few notices:

- with google plus screen sharing, there is no problem at all. it works
  as expected.
- i did notice, the same thing happens, when i tried to use gtk record
  my desktop application. with ffmpeg instead the problem does not occur.
- using unity the problem does not exist.

thanks.

i'v reported a bug on launchpad. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/skype/+bug/879895

if you are having this issue, please comment on the bug and click, the bug affects me

IMPPORTANT UPDATE: i figured that when unticking the option in gtk recordmydesktop of  outlining the capture area, the panel does not disappear. and the problem is solved. the question is how do i disable the outlining of the capture area in skype while sharing desktop

Comment: [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/879895) and as such is now closed.

Comment: i'v reported the bug after posting the question! so why vote down?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to report this on Launchpad as an Ubuntu bug report. They forward such reports to the correct recipient. Please be as precise as possible when doing the report.