# How does one go about satisfying dependencies for a package in a ppa that rely on packages with binary components?

Tags: ppa, dependencies

Simplest explanation of the question is, you can't put any binary components on ppa.

How does one go about satisfying dependencies for a package they could put on ppa if they could satisfy dependencies(and possibly how would you satisfy those)?

It's kind of similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317/how-to-upload-package-with-dependencies-to-my-ppa) except that I can't put the dependencies in the PPA since they rely on some binary components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think binary blobs are disallowed by design. The idea, I've always assumed, is that anyone adding your ppa to their system should be able to look at everything that has gone into its packages--to make sure jts packages are safe to run. Since PPA's were designed for open source packages only, that's probably not unreasonable.

Of course you can build such sets of packages on your own machine and host the deb's elsewhere, but I realize that's not really what you want.

Comment: I get your meaning.  I was looking for a way to put something like python-selenium in PPA.