# 12.04 Freezing Up

Tags: installation, 12.04, laptop, freeze, acer

I'm using a new AO722 (acer aspire), new usb and ubuntu is booting into both the desktop and the installer but after a minute everything freezes. I checked the md5sum, using the 32bit iso. Not sure of anything else I can provide.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

You seen this page on the Ubuntu site?:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze

I've had this issue before; the symptoms I saw were the UI would lock up, but the mouse could still move around.  Either that or the computer wouldn't be able to wake up (the screen would stay black).  All of this happened at random intervals, and before the lockup, everything else was operational.  From other answers I've seen on this, it's usually a Graphics driver issue?

Answer (score 0):

Its a wifi/Lan issue. You have to set the boot order to boot from the network. Then enable network boot in the bios.