# Ubuntu freezes at the purple screen ,but if I force re-boot , it shows BusyBox shell with initramfs. Happens 80% time

Tags: freeze, initramfs, busybox

I tried both Ubuntu 11.04,11.10 & 12.04. It frequently freezes at the purple screen (the screen before the 5-dot ubuntu screen) I wait for 10-15 mins and when I force re-boot, it ends up showing the **Ubuntu BusyBox** black screen with **initramfs** prompt.
I checked many forums and many of them said to try this out---->
1.Boot using Ubuntu LiveUSB
2.In terminal,

> sudo fdisk -l

I see sda7 as my linux partition ( I hv windows 7 also installed)

> sudo fsck /dev/sda7

It shows many things.One of them I remeber is "Recovering journal"

and press ENTER for whatever questions asked during the process.Now when I go back ,remove liveUSB and boot Ubuntu normally,it works fine.But the same problem (freezing at the purple screen->force reboot->ends in BusyBox) comes up after 2 or 3 re-boots.

No problems when I install ubuntu 10.04 or 10.10. Then I thought it might be a problem with the kernal I m using.So I installed the kernal which ubuntu 10.10 uses, but it was of no use.The problem still remains.

Someone please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You may have a hardware problem that does not manifest itself with the earlier releases. I would start by doing a memtest to ensure that my RAM is intact. Also I would check at least the SMART of my hard disk for reallocated/pending reallocation sectors.

Comment: The memtest didnt show any problems.

Comment: Now check the hard disk.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).