# Ubuntu 12.04 freezes pre-Grub

Tags: 12.04, boot, freeze

I was running Ubuntu 11.10, and upgraded to 12.04.  After the system rebooted, it began exhibiting the following behaviour:

1)  It loads the BIOS.  I can access the BIOS menu, so I can select what piece of hardware the computer boots from if I need to.
2)  The screen turns purple.
3)  The screen turns black.

Mashing ESC, DEL, etc does nothing after phase 1; in fact, the keyboard and mouse are totally unresponsive.  I cannot even turn numlock off and on.

I tried loading from a Super Grub 2 disc, but while it can detect some two dozen kernels, none of them seem to load properly.  I am booting from a Live CD now, but I'm not sure how I should go about fixing this.

Comment: I would try booting to the livecd.. If that works, I would identify the boot partition with sudo fdisk -l , then I would mount it with mount /dev/<boot_part_e.g., sda1> /mnt, then I would run sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda , per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Comment: Booting from a livecd works fine, sorry I forgot to mention that - in fact, I'm booting from it now.  I went ahead and tried installing grub as you suggested, going to reboot now.  Fingers crossed.

Comment: Tested thoroughly; doing this appears to have had absolutely no impact whatsoever.  Behavior is 100% identical to before I reinstalled grub.

Comment: That's great that the LiveCD works.. Ok, so I'm thinking it might be either the initrd.img or a needed kernel parameter. To test for the initrd.img, I would copy one over from the 11.10 installation into the /boot directory and rename it to whatever the current one is (rename the current one with .old or something first to back it up). http://goo.gl/Fhx9m As for the kernel paramaters, there are a few ways to do it but I would chmod 644 the /boot/grub/grub.cfg and put acpi=off, nomodeset, (try each one, and maybe more) at the end of the Linux kernel line. Prob try kern par changes 1st.

Comment: Even i have a similar problem. I installed ubuntu 12.04 using a usb stick and it worked fine. But whenever i start ubuntu the screen goes black the same way as the OP described. But when i start ubuntu using the bootable-usb disk it starts

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).