# Bootup hangs on "Checking battery state.." after after 12.04 upgrade

Tags: 12.04, boot, upgrade, freeze, battery

I have scanned thru all the posts on this issue. But I have not been able to get a resolution. Has anyone applied a clean fix to this issue?
I had 11.10 on Lenovo Thinkpad T60 and upgraded to 12.04 last night. The boot process freezes on "Checking battery state" message. I have tried startx , backing up the .conf file, nomodeset etc.. options and nothing seems to working. My video driver is 128MB ATI Mobility RADEON X1400.
Any ideas on how to fix this?
Also if I want to move back to 11.10, how can that be done, without doing another clean install and loosing my data.

Thanks in advance.

Vikas

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Askubuntu! First up all, do `backup your valuable data` and tighten your seat belt.Boot your system in to `recovery mode`(select the second option from the boot menu)and login.This option gives you a command line screen where you can check your video driver position by typing this command `jockey-text -h` which will show you the available options for the driver installation.This command is same like `Additional Driver` in GUI.Moreover be a scholar by these posts too http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1970498 and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection

Comment: Thanks Beeju, none of the options you mentioned above worked for me. Any other viable options available for the fix?