# Ubuntu will not install

Tags: 12.04

I downloaded the desktop ISO for Ubuntu 12.04 and burned the ISO to a DVD. When it boots, it loads up to the splash screen and stops until I get impatient and hit enter then it brings uup the language selection screen after which it loads the GUI with the options where I choose install.  At this point the screen goes blank with a flashing cursor on the upper left corner of the screen and that is all it does.  How do I get it to install.

System Config

- Motherboard: Asus A8n-SLI Deluxe
- CPU: AMD 3500 Athalon 64
- Ram: 1 GB
- HD: 300 GB
- Operating System: Windows 8

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

As Jorge Castro has said, this should be [a bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

...Unless the problem is due to bad installation media, or is a known graphics problem. You gave us some information about your computer, but you did not tell us the make and model of your graphics card. You should edit your question to include that. If you end up reporting a bug, you should make sure to include that information in the bug report as well.

You should [MD5 test](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) the Ubuntu `.iso` you downloaded. If that fails, it means the `.iso` file is corrupted, so you'll need to download it again and start over.

If that succeeds, then verify the installation media (whether it's a CD/DVD or USB flash drive). You can use [these instructions](http://zootlinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/check-disc-for-defects-in-ubuntu-1004.html).

If no errors are found, then try using the [`nomodeset` kernel boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132). That can work around some graphics card problems. If that does the trick, you can set `nomodeset` permanently (also using the instructions available through that link).

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue and it seems that it is related to the Nvidia card used. I have found the following workaround:

1. Insert the USB stick/CD disk and, as soon as you see a small icon at the bottom of the screen, press Enter.
2. Choose your language
3. Press F6 (More options).
4. Select "nomodeset" and press Enter (an "x" will appear next to this option).
5. Choose "Install Ubuntu" and follow the usual instalation process.

The install screens will appear with low quality, when once Ubuntu is fully installed, the screen will appear OK.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Same Thing.  It could be that your ACPI is not supported.

[Disable the new card](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/995187/) , [or disable ACPI.](http://www.ehow.com/how_7641485_edit-acpi-bios.html)  Use the second option if you can't find "New Card Interface".

You can also add the `acpi = off` or the `nolapic` parameter to boot properly.